Updating source link urls after publish
We consume a nuget package provided by an external party who we do not have direct access to their repos but we do have an up to date mirror of their repos.
Is it possible to update the repo url in the pdbs to point to our clone of the repo as its unlikely we will get access to their source repo due to complexities around cross company domain accounts etc.
I was thinking I'd need to somehow extract all of the data and parse the pdbs and rewrite them and publish to our own feed but not sure if there's a more "official" approach to handle something like this.
We don't really want to republish the packages from the clone repo and have to maintain separate build pipelines to them just for this process and similarly it wouldn't really be feasible to ask them to publish multiple package versions for just a source url change.
